# Sum of random numbers in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a program in R to sum n random number. However, when I try it for some numbers it won't work.
For example,

```
## rm(list=ls())
random.sum <- function(n) {  
x[1:n] <- ceiling(10*runif(n)) 
cat("x:", x[1:n], "\n") 
return(sum(x)) 
}
x <- rep(100, 10)
show(random.sum(10)) 
show(random.sum(5))
```

when I try to sum 10 random numbers it will give me the correct sum which is

```
show(random.sum(10)) 

x: 1 3 10 1 3 2 8 6 7 9 

[1] 50
```

However, when I try it for the next one which is 5, it won't work,

```
show(random.sum(5))

x: 7 5 6 2 9 
[1] 529
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: You are defining `x` outside the function to have 10 elements, all set to 100. Then inside the function you are updating `n` elements of it. So when you set `n = 5`, you are only updating the first 5 elements. The remaining 5 are still set to `100`

Comment: Curious why we would want to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be something like this (updated as per @Axeman's comment):

```
sum(sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

where the first "10" is your `n` and `min` and `max` define the value range for `runif`.

Also keep `x` local to the function:

```
random.sum <- function(n) {
  x <- sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE)
  cat("x:", x, "\n") 
  return(sum(x))
}
```

Comment: Or `sum(sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE))`.

Comment: @Axeman Actually much better, thanks. I guess I tried to keep it too close to OPs original.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error is the variable scoping rules of R.  Your variable `x` in global scope is copied upon modification, but maintains the dimension of the global declaration.  If you sum over only the first `n` elements with `sum(x[1:n])` you will get the correct answer.

Now, that begs the question, are you trying to modify the global object `x` inside the function?  If that is your intent, the superassignment operator `<<-` can be used.  See the R intro section 10.5 "Assignments within functions" for details.